# How to decouple SDL_Texture from SDL_Renderer?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, decoupling

I have a sprite class which uses an `SDL_Texture` over an `SDL_Surface` in lieu of perfomance. The class looks something like this:

```
class Sprite
{
    public:
        ...

    private:
        SDL_Texture *m_texture;
        SDL_Rect m_blitRect;

        int m_x;
        int m_y;
};
```

Now the problem is when creating an `SDL_Texture` you also need an `SDL_Renderer` object as well as an `SDL_Surface` to create it. Normally this would look something like this:

```
SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
```

The SDL surface can be created and disposed of while creating the texture however, the problem is, I want to be able to have a rendering object that isn't global. I want a decoupled framework and I don't know how to achieve that in this instance. My first thought was to make a renderer class and have it as a constructor argument but that cannot happen as it would complicate things down the road and cannot be an option. Are there any other ways to decouple the two?

Comment: Have a `Texture` that doesn't actually call the SDL_Createxxx method until it's actually needed ?

Comment: Add that as answer so I can mark it correct. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to decouple your `Texture` from the `renderer` and `surface` parameter, I think your best best is to actually delay the call to the `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` until you actually get these arguments.

That way, your `Texture` texture constructor will not use/need these arguments.